# WPf Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I've created a custom control in WPF and I'm having trouble getting it to bind properly.  If I explicitly set the value of the property in the code behind, everything works fine though.

Here's the XAML for the `TextBox` within my control:

```
<TextBox Name="txtText" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And the relevant properties in the code behind are as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextConverter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(Selector));
public static readonly DependencyProperty EntityIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EntityId", typeof(long), typeof(Selector));

public string Text
{
    get
    {
        string result = this.EntityId.ToString();

        if (this.TextConverter != null)
        {
            result = this.TextConverter.Convert(result, null, null, null) as string;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public long EntityId
{
    get
    {
        return (long)this.GetValue(EntityIdProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(EntityIdProperty, value);

        this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("EntityId");
    }
}

public IValueConverter TextConverter
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(TextConverterProperty) as IValueConverter;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(TextConverterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And now the XAML implementation in my Page:

```
<controls:Selector x:Name="txtReferringCase" EntityId="{Binding ReferringDACaseId}" TextConverter="{StaticResource daCaseNumberConverter}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ButtonClicked="txtReferringCase_ButtonClicked" />
```

Now here's the strange part.  I can set the DataContext for the page and nothing happens, but when I uncomment the commented line, the text shows up in my user control with no issues:

```
_caseScreen = new DACaseScreen(itemId);
this.DataContext = _caseScreen;
//this.txtReferringCase.EntityId = _caseScreen.ReferringDACaseId;
```

EDIT:  One other thing I forgot to mention...  If I hit a breakpoint and check the EntityId and Text properties of the control, they both show the values I would expect.  It seems like the UI just isn't updating.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you change the `DataContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and Setters for [DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) should only call `GetValue` and `SetValue` because XAML doesn't use them they are only for convenience. If you want extra behaviour register your `DependencyProperty` passing in a change handler that does what you want.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EntityIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EntityId", typeof(long), typeof(Selector),new UIPropertyMetadata(EntityIdChanged));

public long EntityId
{
    get
    {
        return (long)this.GetValue(EntityIdProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(EntityIdProperty, value);
    }
}

private static void EntityIdChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Selector)sender;
    control.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
}
```

You don't need to call `PropertyChanged` for Dependency Properties. I also needed to change the txtText binding in your `UserControl` setting the source to the control itself not its `DataContext` but if setting the property in code worked for you it should be ok. You may want to rename your control as there is built in control called Selector but its not that important.

Answer (score 0):

Your UI wont be updated until you do an `OnPropertyChanged` call. Setting `DataContext` won't fire this.

In addition you do:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextConverter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(Selector));
public static readonly DependencyProperty EntityIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EntityId", typeof(long), typeof(Selector));
```

But you dont register the Text dependency, only `TextConverter` and EntityId. Meaning, your `OnPropertyChanged` won't work (?) (Or did you just forget to show that line here :) )

Comment: Text doesn't have be a dependency if you don't bind **to** it. You can fire OnPropertyChanged on "Text" even if it's not a dependency property